# WinSCP command to execute command on the server

Tags: automation, putty, winscp

I just wanted to automate the file transfers without opening WinSCP, through script.

Up to some extent I performed the file transfer operation except PuTTY session.

I prepared a `sftprun.cmd` batch file like:

```
D:\winscp\winscp.com /script=D:\winscp_auto\sftpscriptJAC.txt
```

Can you please suggest me to open PuTTY through above mentioned script to execute command on the server?

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

The putty details should be provided under the script file "`sftpscriptJAC`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinSCP can execute remote commands on its own from the script (with some limitations), using the [`call` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_call):

```
open sftp://user@example.com/
put C:\file.txt
call mount -o remount,rw /
```